# How to unclick other button using 1 button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 15 buttons, each button has content, but when I clicked button1 and followed by button 2, the button 1 is still open. How can I close the button 1 if I click button2?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
div.panel {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">The Ball</button>

<div class="panel">
  <h1>The Ball</h1>
</div>

 <button class="accordion">The Cat</button>

<div class="panel">
  <h1>The Cat</h1>
</div>


 <button class="accordion">The Dog</button>

<div class="panel">
  <h1>The Dog</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: recreating radio buttons?

Comment: You need to toggle off active on the old accordian:
`document.getElementsByClassName('accordian active')[0].classList.toggle('active')` before `this.classList.toggle("active");`

Comment: Usually you would set all to inactive before setting 1 to active, or you have a variable storing the index of the last clicked, and when you click another one you:
1. set the last clicked to unclicked
2. set the currently clicked to clicked
3. set the variable of last clicked to the currently clicked

Comment: Your demo only has one button, I don't understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `active` and `show` classes from previous div before adding them to clicked div.

Your JS Code will be:

```
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        var previous = document.querySelector(".active"); //select previous button
        if (previous) { // check because when first time no button has active class
          previous.classList.remove("active");
          previous.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
        }
        this.classList.add("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
      };
    }
```

```js
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        var previous = document.querySelector(".active");
        if (previous) {
          previous.classList.remove("active");
          previous.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
        }
        this.classList.add("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
      };
    }
```

```css
 div.panel {
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    div.panel.show {
      opacity: 1;
      max-width: 900px;
    }
```

```html
<button class="accordion">The Ball</button>

    <div class="panel">
      <h1>The Ball</h1>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">The dog</button>

    <div class="panel">
      <h1>The dog</h1>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">The cat</button>

    <div class="panel">
      <h1>The cat</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So select the active one. If it is active remove it. If the current one is not the active class add it.

```js
// select all the buttons
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion')
// loop over
btns.forEach(function (btn) {
   // bind the click
   btn.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
     // stop button click
     evt.preventDefault()
     // find the active one
     var active = document.querySelector('.accordion.active')
     // see if active button is the clicked button
     var isSame = active == btn
     // if we have an active button, remove the class
     if (active) active.classList.remove('active')
     // if the current button was not the active one add the class
     if (!isSame) btn.classList.add('active')
   })
})
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
button + div {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button.active {
  background-color: green;
}

button.active + div {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">The Ball 1</button>
<div><p>Ball 1</p><p>bounce bounce poounce</p></div>
<button class="accordion">The Ball 2</button>
<div><p>Ball 2</p><p> bounce pop</p></div>
<button class="accordion">The Ball 3</button>
<div><p>Ball 3</p><p>bounce bounce over the fence</p></div>
```

Comment: it worked! thankyou for the step by step i really understand it

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using JQuery.

I have changed the CSS to remove max-width and opacity and have set .panel elements to be display: none; initially:

```
div.panel {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

And using JQuery, whenever we click an .accordion element, we hide the .panel elements (in case any others are showing), and then show the one that relates to the specifically clicked .accordion element.

```
// register clicks on accordion elements
$('.accordion').click(function() {
  // hide each .panel related to every .accordion element
  $('.accordion').next().hide();
  // show the .panel next to our clicked .accordion element
  $(this).next().show();
})
```